# How does the value of a static variable change?

Tags: java

I have the below code:

```
public class Main {

  public static List<Integer> ODD_NUMBERS = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
      ODD_NUMBERS.add(2*i+1);

    System.out.println("1. oddNumbers:    "+String.valueOf(ODD_NUMBERS));

    addEvenNumbers(ODD_NUMBERS);

    System.out.println("3. oddNumbers:    "+String.valueOf(ODD_NUMBERS));
  }

  private static void addEvenNumbers(List<Integer> listOfNumbers) {

    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
      listOfNumbers.add(2*i);
    }

    System.out.println("2. listOfNumbers: "+String.valueOf(listOfNumbers));
  }

}
```

and the following outputs:

```
1. oddNumbers:    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
2. listOfNumbers: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
3. oddNumbers:    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

**I have some difficulties in understanding how a static field is changing!!!**

Given that I have `ODD_NUMBERS` as `static` list of `integer numbers` which is filled by the odd numbers. But then I send this list ***as a parameter*** to the `addEvenNumbers` method which adds some `Even integers` into it and the result of the print inside the method is:

```
listOfNumbers: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

But, when i back to the `main()` method and print the static variable `ODD_NUMBERS` then it has the same value as  also changed to the below values `listOfNumbers` like below :

```
 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

The fact that `listOfNumbers` and `ODD_NUMBERS` have identical values surprises me, because the value `listOfNumbers` is a parameter of `addEvenNumbers` and it must have no effect out of this block of code. Also, the method never returns anythings.

So, my question is:

Is it because the parameter of method (`listOfNumbers`) is referenced by an static parameter ?
Can you explain how the static variable changes ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `static`, it’s the regular semantics of copying references in Java.

Comment: It has nothing to do with static variables, and everything with [reference semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: Apologies for perpetuating a common misuse of terminology.